# How to unwrap a div buffered with php ob_start

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In the Middle of a research. How do I unwrap the div with the ID `#fromWhere` in the php script below. The I was able to do was `addClass`. Whenever I try to wrap it, it unwraps almost every other element except itself. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this.

```
<?php   ob_start(); ?>

<div id="fromWhere" >19977</div>

<?php $contents = ob_get_contents(); ?>
```

In my effort to unwrap it, I changed things over to make it look like below because it work when i tried targeting it from an external script.

```
<?php   ob_start(); ?>

<script> $('#fromWhere').unwrap(); </script>

<div id="fromWhere" >19977</div>

<?php $contents = ob_get_contents(); ?>
```

Everything:

**PHP**

```
<?php   ob_start(); ?>

<script> $('#fromWhere').unwrap(); </script>

<div id="fromWhere" > </div>

<?php $contents = ob_get_contents(); ?>

             <?php 


        $params = array(
        'origin'        =>  $contents,
        'destination'   => um_user('postal_zip_code'),
        'sensor'        => 'true',
        'units'         => 'imperial'
    );
$params_string='';
    // Join parameters into URL string
    foreach($params as $var => $val){
        $params_string .= '&' . $var . '=' . urlencode($val);  
    }

// Request URL
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?".ltrim($params_string, '&');

// Make our API request
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Parse the JSON response
$directions = json_decode($return);

//echo"<pre>";
//print_r($directions);

// Show the total distance
echo '<p><strong>Total distance:</strong> ' . $directions->routes[0]->legs[0]->distance->text . '</p>';

    ?>

                        <div id class="distance"></div>
```

jQuery that inserts the content into `#fromWhere`

```
                    $(document).ready(function() { 

     var from = $('#show-here #from').text();
 $(".approved #fromWhere").text(from);

});
```

Comment: Ok, what the heck. You have some HTML, which you URL-encode, and use as the origin parameter in a directions request to the Google Maps API? What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: calculate distance and it works when I put the content into #fromWhere manually